# how to pass value of text to "a href"

Tags: authentication, asp-classic

I need you help me with asp code.
I got a home page that contained User Name and Password for user to log in by using **a href** attribute and i don't know how to **pass the value of text** to **a href** to **login.asp file**.
Please help me!

Example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>User</td>
<td><input type="text" id="user"/></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Password</td>
       <td><input type="password" id="pass"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><a href="login.asp?user=?????????????">Log in</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The <form> tag in html? Have you tried searching online for such an example?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the username and password text box must be inside a form element

e.g.

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="login.asp">
 <input type="text" name="username"/>
 <input type="password" name="password"/>
 <a href="#" onclick="document.myForm.submit()">Login</a>
</form>
```

and in your .asp page you can get the values as

```
Request.Form("username")
Request.Form("password")
```